# Change/remove next/prev buttons for featherlight gallery

Tags: featherlight.js

Is there a way to change the next/prev buttons? I want to use characters from my site's custom icon webfont instead of an external image like the default.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can specify](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight#gallery-configuration) a different `previousIcon` and `nextIcon`.

If that doesn't do it, you can modify the layout in your own `afterOpen`.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.